# Single page web application fullscreen scroll

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application, fullpage.js

I have a question regarding the SPA websites with only one page presenting that you scroll through without ever "changing" page. What is this concept called?

Is it 'fullPage.js' or what is this concept and does anyone know where i can read more about it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the scroll functionality used by [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/), that's basically using a technique called "scroll hijacking" or "mouse hijacking", which catches the scroll / mouse events to fire custom actions.

Personally I like to call the resulting effect "full screen scrolling website".

If you are talking about a website with only a single page, you can commonly call them "one page" website or "single page".
Good examples or those can be found in https://onepagelove.com/ or http://www.awwwards.com/websites/single-page/